# How would I access an Image file inside my soloution in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am trying to set the background of a programmatically created Canvas, Using the following method:

```
Canvas Object = new Canvas();
Object.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pages/Asset/Untitled 6.png", UriKind.Relative)));
```

This URI **WOULD WORK** In XAML, for setting a background image however in C# the scope seems to be in a different folder.

> [image: Some XAML With SAME URI That Works]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to write the following code in cs file:

```
 this.Content = Object;
```

And you can set the "**Build Action**" to "**Content**" and "**Copy to Output Directory**" to "**Copy always**" in the **Properties** of the picture.

Comment: You would typically use an image file as assembly resource, i.e. set its Build Action to Resource and not copy it to the output directory.